# How to get parameterized type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Please follow the code snippet

```
public class A<T> {

private T genericInstance() {
    T target = null;
    try {
        Class<T> clazz = getGenericClass();
        target = clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return target;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Class<T> getGenericClass() {
    ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    Type[] types = type.getActualTypeArguments();
    return (Class<T>) types[0];
}

}
```

while I execute the code `getGenericClass()` its return the the Generic Super class but my requirement is to get class of `T` and want to instantiate it dynamically.

Comment: Then why are you calling `getGenericSuperclass()`? `genericInstance()` does what you ask for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of `T` (or to pass in the `class`) because of type-erasure. Java generics provide compile time type-checking only, at run-time the generic is of type `Object`. In practice, this is not difficult, because you know the type `T` at compile-time; for example, `A<Integer> a = new A<Integer>(Integer.class); // Integer.class matches the other Integer(s)`

```
public class A<T> {
  private Class<T> clazz;

  public A(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public T genericInstance() {
    T target = null;
    try {
      // Class<T> clazz = getGenericClass();
      target = clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return target;
  }
}
```

Comment: In this process I should pass Class of `T` to instantiate `T` but me is idle enough not to pass Class of 'T' or instance of 'T'. I want to get it dynamically that's the problem/issue for me.

Comment: I want Christina Hendricks, peace on earth and honest politicians. But she said no, people can't get along and politicians lie. Such is life.

Comment: @ShahedHossain Your request is impossible due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html); in contrast my list is merely improbable.